# OAuth 2 status and new API

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0

OAuth 2 is getting more popular, however its proposed [standard is still a draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23), and is now at version 23, while [most implementations](http://oauth.net/2/) lag well behind that. So my question is - if I'm going to build my new webservice API featuring OAuth 2, should I regard current draft as stable enough? Is there any roadmap documents as for when it would be official? Are there any recommended reference implementations - client/server side - that I could use to test against them? I'm seeing now that everybody implements different thing and calls it "OAuth 2" - so what should I use to not have my API obsolete before it's released? What should I test against?

Comment: This question is well suited for the working group: https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/oauth

In addition, the OAuth2 resources page is a nice reference for other working implementations: http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/25236487/OAuth%202

Comment: Well, the draft now in v25, and none of the references there go past v20, most of them on v10 or below...